# spring-cloud-aws sqslistener stops listen after a period and release notes

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws, sqslistener

I am having a problem where @sqsListener stops listen to new sqs message after some time (between a week to two weeks). There are not error in the log and no information that provide any clearance for why this happen.

I saw that springboot 2.7.10 (the one we use) brings the version spring-cloud-aws:2.2.0.RELEASE. In maven central I can see that there are newer versions up to 2.2.6.RELEASE.

May be there is a change in newer version that fixed this issue, but I cannot find the release notes for spring-cloud-aws.

So my questions are:

1. Is anyone had this type of issue?
2. Can anyone provide a link for the release notes?